# TestComplete/JScript- Using a variable in an object path

Tags: ui-automation, jscript, testcomplete

I am using TestComplete with JScript testing a webpage that has elements that I declare as a variable to make it easier to test the element later.  They all have a path like:

```
var check1 = Window.Panel(1).Panel(2).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Panel(0).Label(0).Checkbox(0)
```

The elements are dynamic, so there is no telling how many there are when the test is run.  I was hoping there was some way to loop through and declare the elements, but it would involve declaring the element like this:

```
var check1 = Window.Panel(1).Panel(2).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Panel(0).Label(x).Checkbox(0)
```

where x is the counter variable.  The problem is that TestComplete sees this as a literal path and does not recognize x as a variable.

Is there any way to do this with TestComplete using JScript?  Or convert a string to an object?  I think I can work with that, too.

Comment: Can you put here the code that assigns a value to 'x'?

Comment: x=1;  It's just a variable that can increment through a loop.

Comment: Well, you can use the aqConvert.VarToInt method to implicitly convert the value of a variable to integer. However, it should have the valid integer type even without conversion. Since I do not see how you declare the 'x' variable and manipulate with it, I suspect that there is something wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that since you store the reference in variable check1, the variable x is updated but the x in variable check1 still holds it's original value (1).

**Workaround**
Keep the first part of the path static in the variable, then update x and assign it to the label.

```
var path = Window.Panel(1).Panel(2).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Panel(0);

// path to the Checkbox
path.Label(x).Checkbox(0);

// or if you want to loop over it
for (var x = 0, len = 8; i < len; x += 1) {
    if (path.Label(x).Checkbox(0).value === 'something') {
        console.log('hooray!');
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to solve.  Some way to use a variable so that it gets the new value as it loops.  This comes up often in my testing, so it would clean up a lot of work arounds that I have to do.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer. If you have any more questions or if it is unclear,let me know.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, but I was finally able to try this method out.  It worked _perfectly_.  I am able to dynamically declare objects.  I actually tweaked it a little to use a while loop instead of a for loop.  I store the objects in an array.

Comment: Great to hear that, do keep in mind that the for loop is a bit faster and does not loop forever like a while loop does.

Comment: Yep, I understand, but since I don't know how many elements there are that I am mapping, I can't use a for loop.  I have an escape condition: If the element doesn't exist, then exit the loop.